# Update по двум таблицам (много ко многим)

Tags: java, postgresql

У меня есть 2 таблицы `User` и `Role`. И так как отношение между ними много ко многим есть третья таблица `User_role`.

При апдейте юзера, как правильно писать запрос чтоб с начала в таблице `user_role` удалялись все записи по данному юзеру, а потом записывались новые (которые приходят при айдейте)?

Сейчас я у меня пока что просто апдейтится юзер, без затрагивания третьей таблицы:

```
"UPDATE \"user\" SET email = ?, first_name  = ?, 
    second_name = ?, last_name = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?";
```

Comment: Обязательно обновлять все данные сразу? Может стоит обновлять "личные данные" отдельно, а роли отдельно?

Comment: Может надо писать 3 запроса? Первый апдейтит таблицу юзера, второй удляет из связующей таблицы все записи связанные с этим юзером. и третий заново записывает роли в связующую таблицу.

Comment: Просто если изменяются только "личные данные", а роли не меняются, зачем их трогать? При обновлении только ролей, какой смысл обновлять другие сведения? Опять же какой смысл при обновлении ролей стирать всё и писать заново, когда можно просто добавить новые роли и/или удалить те, которых у пользователя больше не должно быть?

Comment: изменяются и личные данные, и роли. Смысл в стирании всех ролей при их обновлении в том, что так для меня проще=)

Comment: Пишите столько запросов, сколько надо. Но часто такие запросы надо  выполнять в одной транзакции.

Comment: И все таки это выглядит как костыль -  при обновлении юзера - удалять все роли.   Операция смены ролей у юзера - должна быть отдельной. То есть отдельно обновить данные юзера, и отдельно обновить роли ЕСЛИ нужно.  Ладно  логика хромает.  Но перформанс же просто адски плохой будет.